# Using javascript to reload php function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am using OO php and have the front end page generated through this class, I am trying to reload a button so that once it is pressed it changes class and button all together. Below is the function in which generates the buttons:

```
public static function printStartStopAll($enabled = 'false')
{
    syslog(LOG_INFO, "HELLO");
    ?>
    <div class="big-button-wrapper">
    <?
    if ( is_combined_server() ) {
        // print start all button
        $title_text = dgettext('triplecast', "Start All Transfers");
        $btn_text   = dgettext('triplecast', "Start All");
        if ( !Transfer::CanTransferNow() || count(self::getPendingTransfers()) == 0 ) {
            $class = "big-green-button-off";
            $onclick='';
        } else {
            $class = "big-green-button";
            $onclick = 'onclick=\'startAllTransfers("'.str_replace('"', '\"', self::$txtOpts).'");\'';
        }
        ?>
        <div id='start-all' class='<?=$class?>' title='<?=$title_text?>' <?=$onclick?>><?=$btn_text?></div>
        <?
    }        
    //Separate out the text for readability.
    $title_text = dgettext('triplecast', "Stop Transfers and disable the system till you re-enable it in the configuration menu");
    $btn_text   = dgettext('triplecast', "Stop All");
    $confirm_msg= dgettext('triplecast', 'If you continue all current transfers will be stopped and the system disabled till you re-enable it.');
    $confirm    = dgettext('triplecast', 'Do you want to stop all transfers?');
    ?>
    <div id='stop-all' class='big-red-button' title='<?=$title_text?>' onclick='stopAllTransfers("<?=$confirm_msg.'\n\n'.$confirm?>", "<?=str_replace('"', '\"', self::$txtOpts)?>");'><?=$btn_text?></div>
    <?
    syslog(LOG_INFO, "===>".$enabled);
    if($enabled != "true") {
        $title_text = dgettext('triplecast', "Enable Select");
        $btn_text   = dgettext('triplecast', "Select");
        $class = "big-green-button";
        $onclick='onclick=\'enableSelect(true);\'';
         ?>
        <div id='enable_select' class='<?=$class?>' title='<?=$title_text?>' <?=$onclick?>><?=$btn_text?></div>
        <?
    }
    else {
        $title_text = dgettext('triplecast', "Stop selected Transfers");
        $btn_text   = dgettext('triplecast', "Stop Selected");
        ?>
        <div id='stop-select' class='big-red-button' title='<?=$title_text?>' onclick=''><?=$btn_text?></div>
        <?
    }
    ?>
    </div>
    <?
}
```

Please ignore any syslog :) thats me testing ...

I use ajax to push a variable back to the page and reload this function.

```
function enableSelect(value)
{
$.getJSON("ajax_requests/enableSelect.php", { enabled: value },
    function(data){
});
}

<?php
$requireAuthentication = false;
$requireLicensing = false;
$minimalIncludes = true; 
require_once('../Library.php');
header('content-type: application/json');

$enabled = getParameter('enabled');
$dist_server = TriplecastConfig::get('distribution_server');
$resp = new TriplecastMsg();


try {
TransferController::setSelectEnabled($enabled);
TransferController::printStartStopAll($enabled);
} catch (Exception $e) {
$resp->setCode(STATUS_ERROR);
$resp->setMessage($e->getMessage());
}

$json = new JSON();
echo $json->encode( array("code" => $resp->getCode(), "message" => $resp->getMessage())
```

);
    ?>

I understand that the code is messy, im just trying to figure out how to do this properly.

The aim of this is to enable the user to press this button and for it to reload the button with the stop-selected class (big-red-button)

Any help will be gratefully appreciated

Comment: You have to use the ajax call to get the response and update the HTML.

Comment: you are trying to say that you generate the entire  html from php?any reason y u r doing that?

Comment: It was like that before I started working on the product ... trust me i dont like it but every single product we make is like that

Comment: Please focus on what @Pitchinnate said, for that is what your question is about. I don't see anything happening with ajax responses.